# Still getting Ecto.Association.NotLoaded after using Repo.preload

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm still getting Ecto.Association.NotLoaded even after preloading with Repo.preload(). I have a store schema that has_many :books, when I try to add a create store, I get this error:

```
%App.Stores.Store{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "stores">, 
name: "mystore", description: "book store", id: 13, inserted_at: 
N[2018-10-10 16:52:24.155385], name: "mystore", books: 
#Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :books is not loaded>, 
updated_at: ~N[2018-10-10 16:52:24.155397]}
```

I have researched and found out that my :books association was not loaded, so I added this to my store context

```
def list_stores do
    Repo.all(Store)
    Repo.preload(:books)
end
```

But still getting the same error.

Please this is my schema

```
 schema "stores" do
    field :description, :string
    field :name, :string
    has_many :books, Myapp.Books.Book
    field :owner, :string

 timestamps()
end

 @doc false
 def changeset(store, attrs) do
    market
    |> cast(attrs, [:name, :description, :owner])
    |> validate_required([:name, :owner ])
end
```

and

```
 schema "books" do
    field :title, :string
    field :author, :string
    belongs_to :store_id, Myapp.Stores.Store

    timestamps()
  end

  @doc false
  def changeset(pair, attrs) do
    pair
    |> cast(attrs, [:name, :description])
    |> validate_required([:name, :description])
  end
```

and lastly my migration file

```
def change do
    create table(:books) do
      add :title, :string
      add :name, :string
      add :store_id, references(:stores, on_delete: :nothing)

      timestamps()
    end

    create index(:books, [:store_id])
  end
end
```

Please, I don't understand, I'm new to elixir and have researched for other solutions since the preload is not working. It seems I messed up somewhere in my code, please where did I get it wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't even know how that is compiling. `Repo.preload(:books)` should be failing because the preload function should be expecting more than one parameter.

Comment: Thanks, I finally figured it out. And about the preload, I will study up on it, thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out, it was my StoreView. I removed store.title from the schema and was still calling it on the View. I can add new books and stores now. Can't believe this little thing kept me for long, thanks guys for all your contributions. Really appreciated!

Thank you so much.